# How to reuse intents in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Hello All:
I am creating an application in which I am using menus on every screen for the user to navigate. In my application, I have Screen1--> comes as home screen when the user logs in
Screen2--> user goes to this screen to perform some operations. Now on Screen2 I want to have menu option to let the user go to home screen.
But to start the activity we do

```
startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, Screen2.class));
```

But, I want to use the existing home screen which was created when the used logged in and then using onresume method I can update the home screen.

Can anybody please tell me how to use the existing intents or activity to provide menu options?
Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashwani,

I believe this can be done with a [`setFlags()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) call on your `Intent` using the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) flag.  If screen 1 still exists it will bring it to the foreground.  The documentation doesn't seem to specify, but I assume it launches a new Activity of Screen 1 was killed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute of  element. Is "singleTop" launch mode is what you mean by "use existing home screen"? If you use "singleTop" the activity is not recreated, but receives onNewIntent() signal.

Comment: using the same screen, here I meant that already I am having home screen, so is there any way to get the same reference, instead of creating new one. Or is this expected to create new instance every time?

Comment: the same reference to what?
If you use android:launchMode="singleTop", your screen1 activity won't be created again.